# Skype keeps popping itself to front of focus

Tags: windows-7, skype

With one of the recent updates to Skype v5.1.0.112 for Windows 7, the application now randomly forces itself to the front and distracts me from my task at hand.

It appears to be for advertising purposes, it raises a dialog popup in center that says:

> #### Thank you for using Skype!
>
> Stay up to date on the latest Skype news.
> Follow us on:
>
> Skype blog    Facebook    Twitter

Is there a way to suppress this window and not have it raised with forced focus and distract my work flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is now on version 5.3.32.108 at the moment.

I have not witnessed this behaviour and all I can suggest is updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. After installing [Skype 5.7 Beta](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/windows/beta/downloading/) for Windows, this behavior went away.